# Why does `find` not delete the files it found?

Tags: find, cygwin, delete

I'm trying to understand why the `find` command is not deleting files in one particular case. I've got the following command:

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv -name cap_*.jpg
-o -name cap_*.ogg -o -name cap_*.flv -o -name cap_*.mp4 -o -name cap_*.webm -mtime +7
```

Which returns the files I would expect:

```
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160915T193251_620067800.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160915T193322_742708800.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T081046_394767500.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T081125_615129600.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T081129_503678200.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T081255_842394600.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161008_693586800.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161012_749396800.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161043_774132200.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161150_497251900.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161154_437379600.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161337_350955300.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161341_452596000.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161412_870774000.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161443_969064400.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161554_468109900.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161558_378086000.jpg
C:\path\to/Pictures/pmcctv/cap_20160916T161916_668433100.jpg
```

Now if I try to run the same command with `-delete`, the files are not deleted:

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv -name cap_*.jpg -o -name cap_*.ogg
-o -name cap_*.flv -o -name cap_*.mp4 -o -name cap_*.webm -mtime +7 -delete
```

I've also tried with `-exec rm`, but they are also not deleted:

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv -name cap_*.jpg -o -name cap_*.ogg
-o -name cap_*.flv -o -name cap_*.mp4 -o -name cap_*.webm -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

`find` returns no error and the files are owned by me with permissions 644.

Any idea what could be causing this?

(note: I've cut the commands to make it more readable but normally there's no line break)

Comment: The mixed slashes might confuse it, particularly in the `-exec` case.

Comment: Depending on what you meant to do, you may want to add one set of quoted parentheses "(" and ")" around the sequence of -name ... -o -name ... conditions.

Comment: @ThomasDickey No, Cygwin tools treat backslashes like slashes, and have no problem with `-exec`.

Comment: You do know that you can use forward slashes, Unix style, with Cygwin? So instead of `C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv` you could use `/cygdrive/c/path/to/Pictures/pmcctv`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Juxtaposition binds more tightly than the `-o` operator. So your command is equivalent to

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv \( -name cap_*.jpg \) -o \
                                    \( -name cap_*.ogg \) -o \
                                    \( -name cap_*.flv \) -o \
                                    \( -name cap_*.mp4 \) -o \
                                    \( -name cap_*.webm -mtime +7 -delete \)
```

and only week-old files matching `cap_*.webm` are deleted.

In addition, if there are any files matching one of the patterns in the current directory, then that pattern is replaced by the list of matching files. If the pattern matches exactly one file in the current directory, then only the files with the same name will be matched in subdirectories; if it matches two or more files, you get a syntax error.

The command you're looking for is

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv \
     \( -name 'cap_*.jpg' -o -name 'cap_*.ogg' -o -name 'cap_*.flv' -o -name 'cap_*.mp4' -o -name 'cap_*.webm' \) \
     -mtime +7 -delete
```

You can abbreviate it to

```
find C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv \
     -regex '.*/cap_[^/]*\.\(jpg\|ogg\|flv\|mp4\|webm\)' \
     -mtime +7 -delete
```

Or you can use zsh and in particular its [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `m` to match files by modification time.

```
rm C:\\path\\to\\Pictures\\pmcctv/**/cap_*.(jpg|ogg|flv|mp4|webm)(md+7)
```

Comment: Would "adjacency" be clearer than "juxtaposition"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Juxtaposition is the normal term when talking about grammar (both in linguistics and in CS).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out...

I think this is the 3rd or 4th time I've had to look up why `OR` in GNU find doesn't work the same was as basically every other language/tool.