# Why find -name DIR -exec rm -rf {} + does not remove directories

Tags: bash, find, rm, cmake

I want to cleanup my cmake project and run this command

```
find -name CMakeFiles -o -name CMakeCache.txt -exec rm -rf "{}" +
```

It deletes files CMakeCache.txt but refuses to remove directories. So I have to workaround it with this hack

```
find -name CMakeFiles | while read line; do rm -rf $line; done
```

Does anybody know what might be the reason why find/rm behaves this way and how to make it work properly?

**Update**:

I found out. The problem is in operator precedence. Operator `-o` makes `-exec` work only for the second operand `CMakeCache.txt` . So the correct syntax needs parens `()`

```
find \( -name CMakeFiles -o -name CMakeCache.txt \) -exec rm -rf "{}" +
```

Thanks for posting the related question.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does find not delete the files it found?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310667/why-does-find-not-delete-the-files-it-found)

Comment: Your find command works fine for me.Here is the directory :/tmp/CMakeFiles/CMakeCache.txt.I am running centos7,executing find command under /tmp.May be better if you double quote the file name or directory name when using find.              find -name "CMakeCache.txt" -o -name "CMakeFiles" -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: Are you sure that's your command? It looks to me like it should delete `CMakeFiles` but not `CMakeCache.txt`. Swapping the order of the `-o` would cause the result you're seeing.

Comment: @Barmar  thanks guys, it looks like I had the same problem as in that question. My question has a mistake in one of statements. So this might be confusing because it didn't make any sense. In my code excerpt I put CMakeCache.txt prior to CMakeFiles. In fact the order was vice versa.